# Convert MutableLiveData to MutableState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mutablelivedata

I am new to jetpack compose. I have this value which is a MutableLiveData. I want ofc to observe on the object and get the value. I was wondering if i could convert the MutableLiveData to MutableState in an easy way? To make it even simpler, or is it best to keep it as a MutableLiveData?

Comment: No it is better to use `MutableState` instead of `LiveData` if your app is fully built in Compose.

Comment: Why even declare it as a `MutableLiveData` object? Just initialize it as `val a by mutableStateOf(/*You Data Here*/)`. What's the issue? It can be used even in the `ViewModel`

Comment: Add more details about the use case maybe to get a better approach if any. Otherwise, accept Abhimanyu's answer. It is the actual way to convert it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `observeAsState()` to convert `LiveData` to `State`.
Use `LiveData` in `ViewModel`, `Repository` and other layers.
Convert and observe it using `observeAsState()` in the Composable.

Example code

```
val itemState by viewModel.itemsLiveData.observeAsState()
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: If you do this, remember to add this dependency:
`implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.0")`